# Regex woes and parsing a string correctly

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to match parse a string through regex.  This is what I have so far:

```
 private string result =  @"Range:\s*(?<start>.+\S)\s*to\s*(?<end>.+\S)[\S\s]+For more information, click the link below";
```

And code to parse:

```
start = Convert.ToDateTime(matches.Groups["start"].Value)
end = Convert.ToDateTime(matches.Groups["end"].Value)
```

Here's an example string input:

> Range:Jun 8, 2016 to Jun 9, 2016
>   For more information, click the link
>   below

The `start` variable is as expected below:

> 6/8/2016 12:00:00 AM

The `end` variable is throwing an error on formatting as `DateTime`.  When I output the value of the `end` regex match, it comes out like this:

> 9 Jun 2016 For more infor.....

What am I missing in my regex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have the result you describe if the text `For more information, click the link below` does not appear on a separate line.

If the newline character is not following the date, `.+` will consume all characters until the next newline, which will only be matched by `\s` with the string. This is because `+` is greedy. To make it lazy, add the question mark. Because it is lazy, you don't really need the `\S` within the capture groups:

```
Range:\s*(.+?)\s*to\s*(.+?)\s*For more information, click the link below
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this pattern :

```
@"Range:(?<start>\w+ \d+, \d+) to (?<end>\w+ \d+, \d+)"
```

Just in case, you do need to match the 2nd part :

```
@"Range:(?<start>\w+ \d+, \d+) to (?<end>\w+ \d+, \d+)\r\nFor more information, click the link below";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://txt2re.com/index-csharp.php3/) website.  The regex it generates is a little long but it's worked for me.